# k.m.a.c.KafkaManagedOffsetCache - Failed to process a message from offset topic

Tags: apache-kafka, yahoo-kafka-manager

We are using the kafka 0.8 version and kafka manager 1.3 .

how to resolve this error?

```
[ESC[33mwarnESC[0m] k.m.a.c.KafkaManagedOffsetCache - Failed to process a message from offset topic!
kafka.common.KafkaException: Unknown offset schema version 1
        at kafka.server.OffsetManager$.schemaFor(OffsetManager.scala:380) ~[org.apache.kafka.kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
        at kafka.server.OffsetManager$.readMessageKey(OffsetManager.scala:427) ~[org.apache.kafka.kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(KafkaStateActor.scala:124) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(KafkaStateActor.scala:113) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Success.foreach(Try.scala:236) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache$$anonfun$run$3.apply(KafkaStateActor.scala:113) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache$$anonfun$run$3.apply(KafkaStateActor.scala:108) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Success.foreach(Try.scala:236) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache.run(KafkaStateActor.scala:108) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
[ESC[33mwarnESC[0m] k.m.a.c.KafkaManagedOffsetCache - Failed to process a message from offset topic!
kafka.common.KafkaException: Unknown offset schema version 1
        at kafka.server.OffsetManager$.schemaFor(OffsetManager.scala:380) ~[org.apache.kafka.kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
        at kafka.server.OffsetManager$.readMessageKey(OffsetManager.scala:427) ~[org.apache.kafka.kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(KafkaStateActor.scala:124) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache$$anonfun$run$3$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(KafkaStateActor.scala:113) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Success.foreach(Try.scala:236) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache$$anonfun$run$3.apply(KafkaStateActor.scala:113) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache$$anonfun$run$3.apply(KafkaStateActor.scala:108) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at scala.util.Success.foreach(Try.scala:236) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache.run(KafkaStateActor.scala:108) [kafka-manager.kafka-manager-1.3.0.4-sans-externalized.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

Comment: One suggestion would be to upgrade your cluster

Comment: Will do but i want to know why is this error been generated and what is the cause for it. so as to have a knowledge on this as i am a starter in this technology.

Comment: It's very possible that the Kafka libraries that CMAK are using are not compatible with the Kafka server version you're using https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

Comment: Thank you @OneCricketeer i have deleted the cluster which is of different kafka version which is not compatible with present kafka manger version and now it is working fine. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> `Unknown offset schema version 1`

It's very possible that the Kafka libraries that CMAK are using are not compatible with the Kafka server version you're using - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix

You'll need to upgrade the cluster to use that tool